# Добавить новый ключ к элементу массива

Tags: массивы, php

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить новый ключ к элементу массива?

Есть цикл создания массива:

```
foreach ($result as $element)
{
     $array_result_MO[] = $element;
     $array_result_MO[] = array
     (
          'FILLING' => 1,
      );
}
```

Получаю не то, что хочу:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 123
            [NAME] => Имя
            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Текст
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [FILLING] => 1
        )
```

А хочу вот такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 123
            [NAME] => Имя
            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Текст
            [FILLING] => 1
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Легко:

```
    foreach ($result as $k=>$element){
     $array_result_MO[$k] = $element;
     $array_result_MO[$k]['FILLING'] = 1
}
```

[Мануал](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @Victor Halauko блестяще ), спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Альтернатива:

```
foreach ($result as $element)
{
     $element['FILLING'] = 1; // нет, с оригинальным массивом ничего не произойдет
     $array_result_MO[] = $element;
}
```

Comment: Альтернатива: ))
foreach ($result as $k=>$val)

{

$result[$k]['FILLING'] = 1;

}

$array_result_MO = result;